# Brezis, Functional Analysis, $L^p$ compactness criterion

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

So, I've recently studied Brezis' Functional Analysis book. In Chapter 4, we have the following:

**Theorem 4.26 - (Kolmogorov, Riesz.)** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a bounded set in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $1\le p < \infty.$ Assume that
$$\lim_{|h|\to 0} \|f(\cdot + h) - f(\cdot)\|_p = 0 \text{ uniformly in }f.$$
Then the closure of $\mathcal{F}|_{\Omega}$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ is compact for any measurable $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $|\Omega|<\infty$.

So I've gone through the proof and I believe I have understood it well - but to be honest, I cannot think of any concrete examples where I can apply the theorem.

What are some examples of bounded sequences $\{f_n\}\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ that satisfy the uniform $L^p$-continuity condition? Some examples of bounded sequences $\{f_n\}\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ where the $L^p$-continuity is **not** uniform in $n$?

I apologize if I seem to be "lacking in work," but I really cannot think of any solid examples by myself at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x)$ then the condition from the theorem is violated.

Comment: This is useful to prove compactness of spaces involving bound on differences or gradients, such as Sobolev spaces.